Return cell value to the LEFT of a range of cells if the range contains specific text in GOOGLE SHEETS
I used IMPORTXML in cell A1 to import the descriptions of perfumes on a web page.  I want to be able to show only the last paragraph of each description, because that's where the scent notes are mentioned.  Sometimes, the perfumer will add several commentary paragraphs, or a poem or something like that.  The last paragraph of the description is always followed by specific text in the next cell:  "AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on the_content".
I want a formula that will search from B1:BQ1 and find the text "AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on the_content", and then only return the value TO THE LEFT of that cell.  Using the range B1:BQ1, that text could be in any cell, depending upon the length of paragraphs in each unique perfume description.
Perfume Spreadsheet
I've tried:
=INDEX(B1:BQ1, 1), which returns the value in B1.
=XLOOKUP(C1, $C$1:$C$1000, $B$1:$B$1000), which returns the value in B1.
=XLOOKUP($C$1, C2:CQ2, C2:CQ2), which returns the value in C1 (AddThis etc...).
=offset(C1,0,-1), returns the value in B1.
=XLOOKUP($C$1, C2:CQ2, C2:CQ2), which returns the C1 "AddThis" value.
=INDEX(B1:BQ1, 1, 1), returns the value in B1.
These don't serve my purpose because I never know if the scent notes will be in the first paragraph (B1) or any other paragraph (C1, D1, E1, etc...).
For reference, I never know how many paragraphs the perfumer will use to describe the perfumes.  If there are no descriptions and only scent notes, like in B1 of my spreadsheet, then the text "AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on the_content" will be in the next cell to the right (C1).  BUT... if there are multiple paragraphs describing the scent, then the scent notes could be in any cell up to BQ.  And BQ is only relative for the Yule 2024 perfumes.  Yule 2025, when imported, could have many more descriptive paragraphs and go up to ZZ, for example, before the text "AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on the_content" is found.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=byrow(importxml("https://blackphoenixalchemylab.com/product-category/yule-2024/","//*[@class='description']"),lambda(Σ,
       substitute(choosecols(Σ,xmatch(" AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on the_content ",Σ)-1),char(10)," ")))



Put this formula in cell BS1:
=tocol( 
  byrow(B1:BQ, lambda(row, 
    filter(row, offset(row, 0, 1) = "AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on the_content") 
  )), 
  3 
)

See
byrow(),
filter(),
offset()
and
tocol().
